# Highcharts Pie Donut Customize shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, pie-chart

I need to customize [hightcharts pie donut](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut) for the following design:

[image]

Q: How can I customize circles to form **C shape** and **arrow like shape** ?

[old jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omeraslam/GfYem/)

**Edited:**

Thanks Bochan, [revised jsfiddle: see sample](http://jsfiddle.net/omeraslam07/trHvU/)

Now, I tried to make orange and blue dots([marker](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker)) between two points, According to the documentation, I wrote following code; but it is not showing marker:

```
 plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            pointWidth: '2',
            borderWidth: '0',
            innerSize: '60%',
            animation: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            states: {
                hover:{
                     marker:{
                       fillColor: 'red',
                       lineWidth: 2,
                       lineColor: 'blue',
                       radius: 2
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

[sample shows marker on line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-fillcolor/) I need similar.

[**My jsfiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/omeraslam07/trHvU/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use donut chart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut and renderer to add arrow. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Comment: Thanks Bochan, good idea! I am able to draw it. One thing more: how can I shape the extreme / connectors of two colors with small circles ? thanks

Comment: You can use fill parameter in attr({ fill:'red'})

Comment: Bochan, I am unable to make dots on marker
kindly can you help?
http://jsfiddle.net/omeraslam07/trHvU/

Comment: By renderer, you cannot add ?